# How to change the billing tier option in bigquery APIs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-bigquery

I am using bigquery APIs in my google app script something like:

```
  try {  
   var queryRequest = BigQuery.newQueryRequest();
   queryRequest.setQuery(sql).setTimeoutMs(100000);
   queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(queryRequest, projectNumber);
    // Browser.msgBox(queryRequest);
  }
  catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
    return;
  }
  // Check on status of the Query Job : MONTHLY 
  while (queryResults.getJobComplete() == false) {
    try {
      queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectNumber, queryResults.jobId);
      //queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectNumber, job.id);
    }
    catch (err) {
      Logger.log(err);
      Browser.msgBox(err);
      return;
    }
  }
```

It is giving me:

```
Exception: Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 3 or higher required.
```

I saw the similar error at cloud.bigquery, when writing the query in bigquery console there I can remove it by selecting the billing tier as unlimited but I don't know how to do it through the API (automated way). Is there any way we can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jobs: getQueryResults API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) just retrieves the results of a query job
The "issue" with billing tier happened before – when you called query job via [Jobs: insert API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert)
So, controlling max billing tier should be applied here by using [configuration.query.maximumBillingTier](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.maximumBillingTier) property

Comment: I have updated the question with APIs I am using, Can you point out where should I make the changes because I am not using insert api. Is it necessary to use that?

Comment: I would suggest to try using insert query job - as it has ability to set maximumBillingTier

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply for a higher quota in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
You can go to **Google APIs** -> **BigQuery API** -> **Quotas** then select for **Apply for higher quota**. You can also check here the [**Pricing details**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing?hl=en_US) and the [**Big Quota Policy**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy?hl=en_US&_ga=1.123469259.1935327455.1459248144) that provides you the maximum Bigquery limit rate of incoming requests and enforces appropriate quotas on a per-project basis.